# How is SQL Sever able to improve the performance using partitioned tables in a SAN storage environment?

Tags: sql-server, san

Link: [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/partitions/partitioned-tables-and-indexes?view=sql-server-ver15#:~:text=SQL%20Server%20supports%20table%20and,are%20mapped%20into%20individual%20partitions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/partitions/partitioned-tables-and-indexes?view=sql-server-ver15#:%7E:text=SQL%20Server%20supports%20table%20and,are%20mapped%20into%20individual%20partitions).

> SQL Server supports table and index partitioning. The data of
> partitioned tables and indexes is divided into units that may
> optionally be spread across more than one filegroup in a database. The
> data is partitioned horizontally, so that groups of rows are mapped
> into individual partitions.

The benefit of partitions comes from the fact that each partition can be placed on a separate disk, there by allowing for parallel disk access.

However in a SAN storage environment is there any benefit of partitioning because all files are scattered amongst SAN disks.

Answer (score 4):

> The benefit of partitions comes from the fact that each partition can be placed on a separate disk, there by allowing for parallel disk access.

Not at all.  You can spread a single filegroup across multiple disks without partitioning.  And partitioning using separate disks tends to reduce parallel disk access, as queries are often looking for data in a single partition.

The main performance benefit of partitioning are through partition elimination in queries, and rolling-window partition pruning for removing data from very large tables.

Comment: In a SAN storage environment how does partitioning help? Because each file's content is scattered across disks.

Comment: With partition elimination in queries, reducing the IO required to run queries, and in partition pruning, reducing the need to DELETE individual rows.  Which are both unrelated to the storage design.

Answer (score 1):

There is also a benefit in having to read less data, when some of the criteria correspond to the partitioning keys. That will enhance performance no matter which storage.

Comment: In a SAN storage, how does it matter? Because each file's contents are scattered across multiple disks.